# Is it a problem that web3 gives deprecation warnings?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, web3js

Having web3 as a dependency gives deprecation notices like

```
npm WARN deprecated @types/keyv@4.2.0: This is a stub types definition. keyv provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
```

Is this a problem? If it is, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error might be due to the dependencies version in .json file.

I was trying to build a site using [gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/). And after a month or two of the site published, I tried to `npm update` and throws me an error very similar to yours.

```js
npm WARN deprecated multer@1.4.4: Multer 1.x is affected by CVE-2022-24434. This is fixed in v1.4.4-lts.1 which drops support for versions of Node.js before 6. Please upgrade to at least Node.js 6 and version 1.4.4-lts.1 of Multer. If you need support for older versions of Node.js, we are open to accepting patches that would fix the CVE on the main 1.x release line, whilst maintaining compatibility with Node.js 0.10.
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: Moved to 'npm install @sideway/address'
npm WARN deprecated babel-eslint@10.1.0: babel-eslint is now @babel/eslint-parser. This package will no longer receive updates.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: Switch to 'npm install joi'
npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.19: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
npm WARN deprecated gatsby-recipes@0.25.0: gatsby-recipes has been removed from gatsby/gatsby-cli >=4.5.0. Update to gatsby@latest/gatsby-cli@latest to use versions without gatsby-recipes. This package will no longer receive updates.
```

Then I found that npm has a very classy way of showing the dependency version which are mentioned in .json file by using `npm outdated`. Something like this:

```js
$ npm outdated
Package                          Current  Wanted  Latest  Location                                      Depended by
babel-plugin-styled-components    1.13.3  1.13.3   2.0.7  node_modules/babel-plugin-styled-components   portfolio-main
babel-preset-gatsby               1.14.0  1.14.0  2.24.0  node_modules/babel-preset-gatsby              portfolio-main
eslint                            7.32.0  7.32.0  8.26.0  node_modules/eslint                           portfolio-main
gatsby                            3.14.6  3.14.6  4.24.5  node_modules/gatsby                           portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-google-analytics    3.14.0  3.14.0  4.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-google-analytics   portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-image               1.14.2  1.14.2  2.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image              portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-manifest            3.14.0  3.14.0  4.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest           portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-netlify             3.14.0  3.14.0   5.0.1  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-netlify            portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-offline             4.14.0  4.14.0  5.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-offline            portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-react-helmet        4.14.0  4.14.0  5.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet       portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-sharp               3.14.3  3.14.3  4.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp              portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-sitemap             4.10.0  4.10.0  5.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sitemap            portfolio-main
gatsby-plugin-styled-components   4.14.0  4.14.0  5.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-plugin-styled-components  portfolio-main
gatsby-remark-images              5.11.0  5.11.0  6.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-remark-images             portfolio-main
gatsby-remark-prismjs             5.11.0  5.11.0  6.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-remark-prismjs            portfolio-main
gatsby-source-filesystem          3.14.0  3.14.0  4.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem         portfolio-main
gatsby-transformer-remark         4.11.0  4.11.0  5.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-transformer-remark        portfolio-main
gatsby-transformer-sharp          3.14.0  3.14.0  4.24.0  node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp         portfolio-main
husky                              6.0.0   6.0.0   8.0.1  node_modules/husky                            portfolio-main
lint-staged                       10.5.4  10.5.4  13.0.3  node_modules/lint-staged                      portfolio-main
react                             17.0.2  17.0.2  18.2.0  node_modules/react                            portfolio-main
react-dom                         17.0.2  17.0.2  18.2.0  node_modules/react-dom                        portfolio-main
```

I edited all the dependencies one by one to the wanted version before I tried using the `^` right before the version no. Then `npm update` did the trick without any errors. And my `gatsby build` worked like a charm.

I would suggest not to worry about the code you have, if the problem is similar to mine, it's just the dependencies update all the time and we need to keep a note on the version, or just use `^` or `~`, if you want the update automatically.

You can look into this more detail on `npm` [website](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-update).